# Set-ADObject: The object class of the instance object must contain 'top'

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I cannot find any results for this error anywhere online. Calling `Set-ADObject` like so:

```
Set-ADObject -Instance $obj -Server $server -Credential $cred
```

But I get this error:

```
The object class of the instance object must contain 'top'
```

What does this mean?

Comment: What is $obj???

Comment: You're not setting any property.. so there is no operation to perform